# /usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2

Tags: python, xcode

When I try to build up a python project in Xcode, I followed the instruction online which said if I wanna build that I need to do following.

1. File - New - Project - External Build System.
2. File - New - File - Empty.
3. Product - Scheme - Edit Scheme
4. Info - Executable - Other - Python installed directory (/usr/bin/python ,default)
   Debugger(None)
5. Arguments - Arguments Passed On Launch = python file.
6. Options - Working Directory(python file directory).

then I run the project 
An error came out:

> Command /usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2;

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

From [Exit Codes With Special Meaning](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html)

```
2.  Misuse of shell builtins (according to Bash documentation)
    Missing keyword or command, or permission problem (and diff return code on a failed binary file comparison).
```

It looks like you have a permission issue (sudo) or you're not passing the correct parameters to the python executable.

Answer (score 0):

I have just faced the same issue but with a different scenario, I will post my solution here and I hope it helps somebody else:

I'm working in an old App that was built using XCode 6, it builds completely fine no issues. This App have a networking library and it compiles fine in XCode 6 as well.

However, in XCode 7 the network library does not compile and gives the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
Command /usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2
```

So, after some digging I did edit the Makefile (myApp/Makefile) and added the following entry:

```
install:: version
```

So, the error is about the install rule missing, I don't use this in XCode 6 but after adding it the error is gone. Now I can create my archives without issue in XCode 7 =D

Comment: where inside your project's directory was the makefile that you ended up editing?

Comment: @PatNeedham it was in the root eg: myApp/Makefile

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, I met the same issue but my error code is

> make: *** no targets specified and no makefile found . stop.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkqPh.png)

finally I solved it, the following is my method

the build tool patch was default configured before as

> /usr/bin/make

if you wanna run *.py file, you should change the directory as

> /usr/bin/python

build successful
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0Pue.jpg)