# How to use Xcode to compile ("Command /usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2")?

Tags: xcode, compilation

I used to use the Terminal to compile C-programs written in Xcode so far(it is so much easier..). Now i would like to use the debugger as well. 
I found this manual http://classes.engr.oregonstate.edu/eecs/winter2017/cs261-001/Resources/XcodeTutorial.pdf and am trying to act exactly how it suggests.

However, every time i tried to press the 'build' button i got this error:
Command /usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2

The only posts i find regarding this are
[Using CocoaPods stops iOS build using ionic Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584906/using-cocoapods-stops-ios-build-using-ionic-project) (as it concerns cocoapods i guess that plugin is not helpful.)
These guys had a similar problem..
[/usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764653/usr-bin-make-failed-with-exit-code-2) but i do not get the solution in the last post.
If you know what the error wants to tell..please translate it for me.

I realise that this is no programming but rather an i_am_lost_with_Xcode question. Please help though by sending a link to another manual or giving me a hint how to just compile with Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well..it worked out. I created a new project and chose as a template OS X>Application>Command Line Tool. I am not sure how but it builds fine now.